# Convert SVG with embedded fonts to JPEG with ImageMagick

Tags: svg, imagemagick, render

I want to render SVGs with embedded fonts and images to JPEGs on my webserver. I tried ImageMagick, but the embedded fonts are not being used. The fonts of the SVG do change, so I need a way to not install these separately.

How can make ImageMagick use the embedded fonts?

Comment: Can you add a (link to a) sample SVG file? Plus to an example JPEG output demonstrating the problem you see?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321113/svg-to-png-with-custom-fonts-in-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836998/converting-svg-with-custom-fonts-to-png-using-imagemagick.