# imagemagick.net embedded fonts

Tags: azure, svg, imagemagick

Does anyone have experience or insights into how to convert SVG to PNG using ImageMagick.NET where the SVG has custom embedded fonts?

I've seen [similar posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836998/converting-svg-with-custom-fonts-to-png-using-imagemagick) about this, but I'm specifically interested in ImageMagick.*net* and I would like to avoid calling anything from command line.  I currently use Batik, but I want to move this to Azure and I don't want to go through starting the JVM so that the JAR file can be executed.

Note additionally, my problem is that I am getting the SVG from another party and most fonts are not freely available, so I can't just pre-install all potential fonts.

Many thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anything about [[image]azure](/questions/tagged/azure) platform, but I can share some insight on the SVG process within ImageMagick. *This is more of a long-winded comment than an answer*

ImageMagick (of which `Magick.net` sets on top of) performs tasks on raster images, so any vector input must be "decoded" into a raster image before any additional work be be done. For SVG images, I'm aware of three ways ImageMagick can render vector graphics into authenticated pixels.

1. Use a primitive internal MSVG coder to draw each shape.
2. Pass the rendering work to `librsvg` if compiled with delegate library support. (Usually on *NIX systems)
3. Call an external command-line application. Identical to the suggestions referenced in the links you provided.

If I would map it out, I would imagine it would look something like this.

[image: SVG delegate map]

### SVG Fonts with MSVG (option #1)

I believe this is the option your asking about as it would be the default configuration for must ImageMagick installs. For a font to be rendered, the typeface must be found on the system, and supported by freetype (`.ttf` or `.otf` files). Embedded fonts are usually base64 ttf files attached inline under the `@font-face` CSS [at-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/At-rule). If this is true, you should be able to preprocess the document, extract the font-file to a local/temporary filesystem, and assign it with `MagickReadSettings.FontFamily` before reading the SVG document. Although I'm not sure if this would work with multiple fonts.

### SVG Fonts with RSVG (option #2)

The `librsvg` offers a lot more support for SVG specs then the internal renderer, but also enforces more restricted approach for external resources. There's also an [open issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/librsvg/issues/153) with adding support to `@font-face`, so you might be forced to do option #1 anyway.

### External Command-line (option #3)

This would be your best option. ImageMagick's [delegate.xml](https://imagemagick.org/source/delegates.xml) file can be altered to call other utilities. [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/), for example, can be called by ImageMagick with the following rule..

```xml
<delegate decode="svg" command="inkscape.exe -e %o %i"/>
```

Although I'm not sure if inkscape is a good example as support for CSS fonts are still listed on a [wishlist](https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/741135).

**TL;DR**

> ... convert SVG to PNG using ImageMagick.NET where the SVG has custom embedded fonts?

All-n-all, it boils down to *the right tool for the right job*. If your only use-case is converting SVG+CSS to PNG, and you have no additional raster manipulation tasks, a direct utility like `batik` is more appropriate than ImageMagick. Like it or not, installing a JRE to execute a JAR file might be the best option. `Magick.net` by itself doesn't meet your requirements.

Comment: I ended up having to go command line.  The problem is there are thousands of old SVG's with embedded fonts so I can't just install every potential font on the server.  Great answer though, very thorough and illuminating.